# Irrational integral $\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2+5x+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm asking for help to figure out this particular integral
$$ \int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}} $$
I've tried many ways, most of them started with completing the square and applying substitution $u = x + \frac{5}{2}$, but after a while I was stuck at third or fourth substitution struggling with enormously large fractions and propably more difficult integrals. So far no luck, any help will be appreciated. Maybe there's short way to do it without multiple substitutions?

Comment: Your idea is ok. But the numbers are not favorable. It's going to be ugly no matter what

Answer (score 6):

Hint:$$ \int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}}=\int \frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=-\int \frac{d(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{x})^2+\frac{5}{x}+1}} $$

Comment: Very nice trick !

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = \frac{1}{t} \implies dx = -\frac{1}{t^2}dt$ 
$$\therefore \int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}}=-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+5t+1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

With the Euler substitution $\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}=\pm x t_{\pm}+1$
\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x^2+5x+1}}\ dx
=&-\int \frac{1}{\frac52 \mp t_{\pm}}dt_{\pm}= 
-\frac12\ln |\frac{t_-+\frac52}{t_+-\frac52} |\\
=& -\frac12 \ln |\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}+1+\frac52 x}{\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}-1-\frac52 x} |\\
=&-\coth^{-1}\frac{1+\frac52x}{\sqrt{x^2+5x+1}}
\end{align}
which is valid for all domain $x$.