# How do I solve the integral $\int\frac{dz}{z\sqrt{4z+z^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution

The proposed integral is given by

$$\int \frac{dz}{z\sqrt{4z+z^2}}$$

I'm trying to answer this equation using the Reciprocal Substitution method, how should I approach this? Should I rewrite or simplify the equation first before I proceed?

If yes, someone please help me, an answer on this equation and as well an explanation would be so much appreciated too.

Thanks and advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you tell us what are your attempts?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663732/irrational-integral-int-fracdxx-sqrtx25x1?noredirect=1

Comment: Note that if $P(z)$ is quadratic then any integral $\int R(z,P(z))dz$ can be evaluated in elementary functions, where $R$ is a rational function.

Comment: Substitute $x=\frac{1}{t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing squares converts the integral to $$I=\int \frac{1}{z \sqrt{(z+2)^{2}-4}} d z.$$
Let $z+2=2 \sec \theta$, then
$
d z=2 \sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta.
$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int \frac{2 \sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta}{2(\sec \theta-1) 2 \tan \theta} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sec \theta d \theta}{\sec \theta-1} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1-\cos \theta} d \theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1+\cos \theta}{\sin ^{2} \theta} d \theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int \csc ^{2} \theta d \theta+\int \csc \theta \cot \theta d \theta\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(-\cot \theta-\csc \theta)+C \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z+4}{\sqrt{z^{2}+4 z}}\right)+C \\& \stackrel{OR}{=} -\frac{\sqrt{z^{2}+4 z}}{2 z}+C,
\end{aligned}
$$
which is checked by [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bz%20%5Csqrt%7B4%20z%2Bz%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7D%20d%20z).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: rewrite
$$\int \frac{1}{z\sqrt{4z+z^2}}dz =\int \frac{1}{z^2\sqrt{\frac4z+1}}dz = -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac4z+1}}d(\frac1z)$$

Comment: $$ \sqrt{4z+z^2} = |z|\sqrt{ \frac 4z +1   } $$

So this answer works for $z\ge 0$ but should be multiplied by $-1$ if $z \le -4$

Comment: @WW1 - you are correct